# How do I create a progressively dynamic structure in ABAP?

Tags: json, abap

XML tree data

```
<EMPLOYEEDATAROOT>
<id></id>
<EMPLOYEE>
    <EmployeeId></EmployeeId>
    <user_id></user_id>
    <Basic_information>
        <fname></fname>
        <lname></lname>
        ...
        ...
    </Basic_information>
</EMPLOYEE>
```

is flattened and stored in a table like this.

[image]

Type of SPACE means the node has no children.
Type of 'A' means the node has children.
And Hier represents hierarchy.

Now, I need to respond to an incoming HTTP get request with a nested JSON structure of this data. To create JSON, i need a structure.

I started using RTTI. But, since each work area is different - one work area can just be a node, another can just have one level of children, the next one can have grandchildren etc.  RTTI is not entirely possible - or I don't know how to use it.

Any ideas here would be helpful.

Comment: Wait, You get an XML and want to convert it to json ?

Comment: The XML comes in - gets stored in the table. Then periodically certain actions happen on the table.
Then an API needs to respond to incoming HTTP GET requests and respond to it with JSON.

Comment: And according to the data, which already gets properly stored in the internal table, You then want to create a properly nested JSON string respecting the hierarchies ?

Comment: absolutely! That's what I want to do.

Comment: I cannot say with 100 percent certainty, but I tend to say: Either this is Your own parsing problem. OR, Eventually You might use XML-tranformations, which first transform the incomming flat XML into a proper hieracrhical XML (and therefore avoid the internal table completely) and then use built in XML-to-JSON API's to pass the values properly. I had similar problems a long time ago, then I found an online XSLT-tester, created my transformation by studying XSLT's and by try-error. I could solve my problem with that. XML-Transformations are really mighty.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to generate a data structure. Use a [JSON writer](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_json_sxml.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENABAP_JSON_SXML_2) to render the output that you create using [object-oriented rendering](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_sxml_lib_render_oo.htm). [This example](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abensxml_oo_rendering_abexa.htm) shows how to create a document dynamically and render it as XML; it should be trivial to adapt the sample program to use a JSON writer.